# Convert Mp4 Video into a String

Tags: php, string, video

Ok, so this is going to be really complicated to make but I'm trying to make a website in PHP, where you can upload a mp4 video, and the website will convert it to a super long string.

Can I have some help with this?

Thanks,
ProtectedMethod

Comment: What to you mean by "super long string" ? What's the link between the video and the string ?

Comment: Yes , but not on stackoverflow. We make standards that this question is too broad and is also known to be off-fopic for stackoverflow. Sorry but you need to find in other website

Comment: My hunch is that he means BLOB or GLOB instead of string, but off topic for SO

Answer (score 1):

Use phps file_get_contents() to transfer any content of a file into a string.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

However I would not recommend to read a big binary into a string. You would probably run out of ram pretty fast.